# jwt integration django drf

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

i am trying to implement jwt on my django app but i have some confusion

when i make post request on postman with email pass:

```
http:www.127.0.0.1:8000/token/
```

i get refresh and access token:

```
{
"refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU3NDUwMTcxNSwianRpIjoiNDg5YjjZmQyY2IwNDI4YjgxMzg4NDU1YmQ1ZGM3NDYiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjo2fQ.5Bms8FiqOdlIeyi1k1cRcfLC1qmHEH05MysZnzMcKCA",
"access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTc0NDE1NjE1LCJqdGkiOiI1OTBkMGjZjJlYmE0YjNmOTE1MzI5NTEyOGExNzUyMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjZ9.7HZYpD-mCp5li4PnGSuwQGyVa7nsDYvUVWaxdyKYk-E"
}
```

and when i make this:

```
http:www.127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/
```

i get access token:

```
{
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo2LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFrYXNAbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NzQ0MTU4NTYsImVtYWlsIjoiYWthc0BtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTc0NDE1Nzk2fQ.DEpZNq-kFFqYb3ZfAiYDB1CigfY36qpS9o-T7rJ5-_I",
"user": {
    "email": "akas@mail.com",
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$150000$OdHDeKGCViax$BvOXGFheSJoNb692ZVYxoWnZxK2xZQpvbu7HA/SC5Po="
       }
 }
```

then i can make get request when i add this access token in header authorization

i don't understand whats the difference between these two access token?

Answer (score 0):

Your first pair of tokens aren't valid, and they're structurally *extremely* different from your second token.

A JWT has three parts, separated by periods.  ([RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) has the full specification.)  The first part is a header; the third part is a signature; but the middle part is a set of *claims* that's really the interesting content of the token.  The first two parts are just base64 encoded so you can just decode them to see what's inside.  The claims of your first access token look like

```
{"token_type":"access","exp":1574415615,"jti":"590d0hٌ?X?M?َLML̎MLL?LM?L?\?\???
```

but the second one is

```
{"user_id":6,"username":"akas@mail.com","exp":1574415856,"email":"akas@mail.com","orig_iat":1574415796}
```

This suggests to me that you have two different JWT implementations in your application and also that one of them is configured wrong; since the first token can't be decoded as JSON it can't be validly used.

There's one other interesting thing that may be a hint when debugging.  If I take your access token and copy it into the decoder on the https://jwt.io/ front page, and I delete the characters `jZj` in the middle of the token, then I get

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1574415615,
  "jti": "590d0beba4b3f9153295128a17520",
  "user_id": 6
}
```

which (up to the signature) could potentially work.  The different claims between the two tokens still look odd, though.

(`"jti"` is a standard claim for a unique identifier for the token; the most useful application of it is keeping a blacklist of revoked tokens.  There's also a standard `"sub"` claim identifying the subject of a token which would probably take the place of your `"user_id"`.)

Comment: yeah i get like this: {
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1574425263,
  "jti": "5d767446e53746b299d3928d0ba41474",
  "user_id": 6
}

Comment: i also have two implementation jwt and simple jwt

Comment: i dont know conventions should i get token with localhost:8000/token